# Get radio button by name in a loop using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery 1.4.1 and while I plan to upgrade soon, I need to resolve the below issue.  I need to loop over all the radio buttons on my html page and then do some logic for a couple of radio button's based on their name.  Below was my attempt but it's not working, any ideas?

```
jQuery('input:radio').each(function() {
      if(jQuery(this).name('radioOneName')) {
           alert("radioOneName")
      } else {
           alert("not radioOneName")
      }
});
```

Comment: Try using `(this).attr("name");` to get the name attribute.

Comment: @tymeJV - can you add you comment as an answer, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `jQuery(this).attr('name') === 'radioOneName'`. [Link to docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(':radio').each(function () {
            var myval = $(this).val();
            if (myval == "button1")
            {
                alert("first");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("second");
            }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<input type="radio" id="abc" name="myradioname"/>
```

and in javascript using this:

```
$('input[name="myradioname"]').each(function(){
    // do something...
})
```

Basically, this syntax queries the document for the `<input>` tag having the specified name.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
$(this).attr("name");
```

Glad I could help.

Comment: actually it depends.  I'm using JSF and due to the $ sign being used during expressions, you have to use something other than $